# Ninja is required to load C++ extensions after install ninja

Tags: ninja

I want use deepspeed to train a model. It goes fine on shell, but when I want debug on vscode this problem shows up:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPd7k.png)
I have already download the ninja with pip, I don't know if the problem is with vscode or something. Do I need to edit the configuration of vscode?

How can I solve the problem or is there some alternative method to debug？

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ninja+is+required+to+load+c%2B%2B+extensions, and Please: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)